Yaml Pipeline DevOps - Error passing value to template parameter
I am having issues with yaml pipeline and output variable, I suspect it's to do with the output variable being a string. In short, there's a artifact .txt containing JSON items, such items need to be passed to the template parameter. Please see below.
There's a template which contains the following:
parameters:
- name: SolutionNames
  type: object
  default: []

jobs:
  - job:
    dependsOn: 
    - ${{ parameters.DependsOn }}    
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      path: Self
      
    # iterate through each solution
    - ${{ each solution in parameters.SolutionNames }}:
      - template: /Deployment/References/Build/steps/step-build-solution.yml
        parameters:
          SolutionName: ${{ solution }}

Such template is called here. Download artifact and powershell adds the array of strings to an output variable to be passed as a parameter in a subsequent stage. If parameter is string, it goes through fine, however, since it is object, it fails. My understanding is that output variable is always passed as string. In that case, what would be the best approach to tackle this? Such value needs to be iterated through:
- stage: StageVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment
  jobs:
    - job: JobVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment
      steps:
       #- checkout: self
       #  path: Self
       #  persistCredentials: true
       - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
         displayName: 'Downloading artifact to confirm solutions to be deployed'
         inputs:
            buildType: 'specific'
            project: 'D365'
            definition: 3
            buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
            artifactName: 'solutionsExportedArtifact'
            downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

       - task: PowerShell@2
         displayName: 'Verifying solutions to Deploy'
         name: TaskVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment
         inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $txtContent = Get-Content "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\solutionsExported.txt" -Raw
              $solutionsSelectedForImport = $txtContent | ConvertFrom-Json
              
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=formattedString;isOutput=true]$solutionsSelectedForImport"

              
- stage: Build_Solutions
  displayName: "Build Solutions"
  dependsOn: StageVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment
  variables: 
    myOutputVar: $[stageDependencies.StageVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment.JobVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment.outputs['TaskVerifyDataAndOrSolutionDeployment.formattedString']]
  jobs:
    - template: /Deployment/References/Build/stages/stage-build-crm-solutions.yml
      parameters:
        SolutionNames:  $(myOutputVar)


- stage: Deploy_Solution_
  displayName: "Solution Deployment"
  condition: and(succeeded(),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'main'))  
  dependsOn: Build_Solutions
  variables:
  - group: test
  jobs: 
  - template: /Deployment/References/Build/stages/stage-deploy-solutions.yml
    parameters:
      TargetEnvironmentName: 'TEST'
      TargetSPN: 'Service-Principal-TEST'
      IsEnvManaged: '1'
      SolutionNames: $(myOutputVar)

